# Multiple inserts fail with IntegrityError due to failed constraint

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, transactions, mariadb

With Python (SQLAlchemy) and MariaDB, I am trying to perform three inserts, whereby a constraint for the third insert requires the first two to have been successful.  However, currently the third insert fails unless the first two inserts have been committed.  I would like to perform all three inserts within one transaction and rollback if an error occurs.

The code looks like this:

```
try:
    ulcdb.add_person(uid, lang)
    ulcdb.add_group(gid, gid_number)
    ulcdb.add_membership(uid, gid, 'owner')
    ulcdb.commit()
except Exception as e:
    ulcdb.rollback()
    logger.error(str(e))
    raise
```

whereby `ulcdb` is an instance of the following class:

```
class UserLifecycleDatabase:

    def __init__(self):

        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url)
        Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        self.session = Session()

    def commit(self):

        self.session.commit()

    def rollback(self):

        self.session.rollback()

    def add_person(self, uid, lang):

        self.session.add(Person(uid=uid, lang=lang))

    ...
```

If I commit the first two inserts, the third is also successful.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share a proper [mre] please?  We need to see the models / tables and constraints.

Comment: That would entail rather more work than I was hoping would be needed.  I was hoping someone could point out some general conceptual error I am making.  Obviously if that doesn't happen I will indeed need to provide an MRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to run `session.flush()` rather than `session.commit()` after the inserts.  This way the information needed to fulfil the constraint is available to the session and the third insert succeeds.  The whole transaction can then be committed.  If, however, an exception occurs, any inserts which were successful can be rolled back.